# concurrency problem with dropwizard framework and hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, concurrency, kubernetes, dropwizard

An example configuration: two pods within kubernetes based on dropwizard framework with hibernate. Both pods (duplicated) contain the same code and Rest APIs. Both pods access the same DB. With this design I'll get problems with concurrency, right? what is the solution?
Should I lock the DB already in the Resources-layer?
The design is:

> Resources-Layer -> Core-Layer -> DB-Layer based on hibernate...

.

Comment: Please explain what concurrency problems are you concerned with? databases know to keep data consistency across many connections. If the database is responsible for handling consistent data it's unclear how is the concurrency problem related to kubernetes, dropwizard or hibernate

Comment: ok, you're right. It's database design issue. E.g. I can book a resource. The problem is, that the decision if a resource is bookable or not will be decided in the application-logic. And this decision depends on two tables: booking and reservation => Actually for "write" access both tables have to be locked.

Comment: that's what transactions are for. if you need write consistency between two tables you can start a transaction and perform the dual writes.